# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named blogdjango starting the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't know how to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: Is blogdjango one of your apps. What's your settings.py and what is the python version?

Comment: As in the duplicate question, it looks like you are missing a comma after `'blog'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors. Copy and paste the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `blogdjango` to your installed apps in `settings.py`